# google validator (https://validator.schema.org/) at schema.org gives me this error when I pass LD json data inside helmet script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, schema.org, structured-data, react-helmet

[google validator at schema.org gives me this error when I pass LD json data on script like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJWaG.png)

Comment: Sorry this was my first question at stackoveflow and I am not sure why the image preview of the error does not show but please click on ht link to find the error and share a solution to it!

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the data and error message as text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `}` at the end, in line 36. It's better if you paste the code instead of an image.